# navbar background isnt trasnparent but instead the color of the backgrounds completely

Tags: html, css, navbar

So when coding my website i have an issue where when i tried to make the background transparent but it shows like a solid bar instead, could it possibly be embedded into my other code?

```
.navbar {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 5%;
z-index: 1;
display: flex;
background: transparent;}
```

[the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hwCl.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend use **opacity** to make **transparent** background!
Just go through this link on **[W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp)** you will understand the concept of transparency and opacity.

Comment: thank you i went over it and it fixed any issues i have!